# typescript is there a way to remove the array from an property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have this model:

```
export interface SizeAndColors {
   size: string;
   color: string;
}[];
```

and then I have another model and I need the sizeAndColor but without a array.

```
export interface Cart {
  options: SizeAndColors
}
```

How can I say at options that I want to have this interface without the array?
is that possible ?

Comment: You could have two interfaces, `SizeAndColor` and then `SizeAndColorList`.

Comment: Are you sure that `SizeAndColors` is really declared that way? Because the `[]` don't seem to do anything: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZQQC9gBBJAEwGEIAbaAZzgG8AoODuB44ALi5hRkAcwDc7TtjrR+DQSPEBfANoBdca1rB4IfoRLlq0qAw0g4AXhYSO3EvwBEIBwBobcKfSiPnrRaKA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `SizeAndColors` really is declared as an array type where the elements are objects with `size` and `color` properties (what's in the question [doesn't seem to be that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72061927/typescript-is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-array-from-an-property/72061943#comment127329023_72061927)), I'd suggest splitting the original interface:

```typescript
interface SizeAndColorsElement {
    size: string;
    colors: string;
}
export type SizeAndColors = SizeAndColorsElement[];
```

But if you can't, you can use `SizeAndColors[number]` to access just the object part of that:

```typescript
export interface Cart {
    options: SizeAndColors[number];
}
```

**Again:** That's assuming it's really defined as an array type, which it doesn't seem to be in the question's code.

Answer (score 2):

Define you interface like this

```
export interface SizeAndColors {
 size: string;
 color: string;
}
```

and use array only when you need it

```
export interface Cart {
 options: SizeAndColors[]
}
```